# Null terminated string, is it really dictated by the standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, stdstring, c++14

### Discussion

- It is known that from C++11 and beyond `std::basic_string`s are considered to have null character terminated internal storage buffers.
- The main reason for this change, among others, was that the previous definition of `std::basic_string` allowed only very limited concurrent access to strings and thus, limited performance for multi-threaded applications. (More on the reasons for the changes in `std::basic_string` can be read in the [proposal N2534](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2534.html)).
- However, reading the standard I couldn't find a quote where explicitly is stated that `std::basic_string` must have a null character terminated internal storage buffer.
- The only implicit quote that I've found is *§21.4.7.1/1&3 basic_string accessors [string.accessors]:*

> > *`const charT* c_str() const noexcept;`*
> >
> > *`const charT* data() const noexcept;`*
> >
> > *`1` Returns: A pointer `p` such that `p + i == &operator[](i)` for each `i` in `[0,size()]`.*
> >     *`3` Requires: The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array.*

- I assume that due to efficiency reasons and since `§21.4.7.1/3` require that the program shall not alter the returned buffer, most implementers in `std::basic_string::c_str()` and  `std::basic_string::data()` are returning the null character terminated internal buffer.
- However, the standard doesn't state anywhere that the buffer that must be returned by `std::basic_string::c_str()` and `std::basic_string::data()` must be the internal storage buffer of the `std::basic_string` and not some null character terminated copy.

### Questions:

1. Is there somewhere in the standard explicitly stated that `std::basic_string` internal storage buffer must be null character terminated?
2. In case there is not an explicit statement (i.e., question #1 short answer is no), does this mean that an implementer could implement the `std::basic_string` with out a null character terminated internal storage buffer and consequently the wide spread notion that since C++11 strings are null terminated is wrong?

Comment: Part of it is also in their complexities.

Comment: Also I vaguely recall there's at least one `std::string` operation where you can explicitly dereference but not advance the `end` iterator.

Comment: Reading the answers of the duplicate, I'm up to the conclusion that there's not an explicit directive for null terminated buffer but this is implicitly forced. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 5):

From **21.4.5**:

> `const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;` `reference
>   operator[](size_type pos);`
>
> 1 Requires: `pos <= size()`.
>
> 2 Returns:
>   `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`, otherwise a reference to an
>   object of type `T` with value `charT()`; the referenced value shall
>   not be modified.

Note that `s[s.size()]` is well-defined and required to return NUL character.

However, that doesn't by itself require `NUL`-terimnated internal storage. **21.4.1/5** has this to say:

> The char-like objects in a basic_string object shall be stored contiguously. That is, for any `basic_string` object `s`, the identity `&*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n` shall hold for all values of `n` such that `0 <= n < s.size()`.

Note that contiguous storage is only required up to `n < s.size()`, but not for `s.size()` itself. So `char* p = &s[0];` doesn't necessarily point to a `NUL`-terminated buffer, as the standard doesn't require that `p[s.size()]` be valid.

Practically speaking, between requirements on `data()`, `c_str()` and `operator[]`, any sane implementation would maintain a `NUL`-terminated storage. But insane implementations don't appear to be precluded by the standard.

Comment: But that quote does not require the internal storage itself to be null-terminated, only that it requires `[]` to return a reference to internal storage if `< size()` is requested, and a reference to a null character otherwise. That does not require the null to come from internal storage, it could come from an internal constant literal instead (which is what `c_str()` typically returns a pointer to when `size()` is 0). In this quote, there is nothing to require `s[s.size()-1]` and `s[s.size()]` to return references consecutive data in memory.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Quite. I was actually in the process of writing just this in the second half.

Comment: It just occured to me that this is a tricky requirement any way you cut it, because many `string` implementations allocate no memory for default construction.  Since `std::string{}[0]` is required to return a readable reference, so the implementation must special case the `end` no matter what.

Comment: If `s.size()` is 0, `s[0]` returns a reference to a null character, and so `p[0]` is valid. If `s.size()` is >0, `s[0]` returns a reference to the beginning of internal storage, and `p[s.size()]` is valid only if the internal storage is null-terminated.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, `c_str()` and `data()` are both required to return a pointer to the internal storage (sorry, I don't have a direct quote handy to back that up).  In earlier versions, `c_str()` was not require to do that, but `data()` was.  Implementors could (but rarely did) implement copy-on-write semantics so that the pointer returned by `c_str()` was not the original internal storage.

In all versions, `c_str()` is required to return a null-terminated pointer.  So, that implies that in C++11, the internal storage must be null-terminated.

Comment: There's nothing preventing `c_str()` from putting in the null value right before it returns (however, there must already be space for it).

Comment: data() existed in C++03,  What version didn't it exist in?

Comment: @Nevin oh, so it was.  I thought it was new to C++11, but I was mistaken.

Comment: @MooingDuck, you may have been thinking of vector, which didn't get it until C++11.

Comment: @MooingDuck: If the internal storage is large enough, c_str() could insert a null at the end before returning a pointer to the storage. Otherwise, it would have to make a copy of the storage data and then return a pointer to that copy. In earlier versions, that was allowed. In C++11, the data is not allowed to be relocated (ie, copied), which thus implies that internal storage must be large enough to always hold a null, even if it is not actually inserted until `c_str()` is called.